# How do I present multiple check in-check out intervals to clustering algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, mathematical-statistics, clustering

I am trying to cluster employees based on their check in-check out time. 
Employee can check-in/checkout any number of times in a day. My plan is to use one month data.

Please let me know how to represent multiple check in-check out intervals to clustering algorithms ?

Sample test data of 6 employees for a week period 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5f9hxuyr12x26rc/testData.csv?dl=0

*** Initials rows *** 
EmpID,Dept,EventTime,Location
1651589,D2000,2017-08-14 08:39:02,BLDG2-7F-D015 Entry 
1651589,D2000,2017-08-14 10:38:54,BLDG2-7F-D018 Exit 
1651589,D2000,2017-08-14 12:11:26,BLDG2-7F-D018 Entry 
1651589,D2000,2017-08-14 15:11:20,BLDG2-7F-D015 Exit 
62879,D1000,2017-08-14 14:49:15,BLDG1-4F-D004
62879,D1000,2017-08-14 14:47:10,BLDG1-3F-D004
83240,D1000,2017-08-14 10:45:40,BLDG1-4F-D006 Entry
83240,D1000,2017-08-14 11:37:53,BLDG1-4F-D006 Exit
83240,D1000,2017-08-14 12:45:40,BLDG1-4F-D006 Entry
83240,D1000,2017-08-14 13:37:53,BLDG1-4F-D006 Exit
83240,D1000,2017-08-14 15:45:40,BLDG1-4F-D006 Entry
83240,D1000,2017-08-14 17:37:53,BLDG1-4F-D006 Exit
84778,D1000,2017-08-14 14:24:41,BLDG2-GF-G018 Entry
1662394,D2000,2017-08-14 14:13:11,BLDG2-1F-G025 Entry
1662394,D2000,2017-08-14 14:12:19,BLDG2-1F-G025 Exit
84778,D1000,2017-08-14 14:11:17,BLDG1-GF-G003 Exit

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do they check-in and check-out on a daily basis? If so, then I would suggest to make (at least) three numeric features out of it: seconds after midnight (of the same day) they checked in, the same with checked out and the duration of their stay. Then feed the dataset with these three numeric features to some arbitrary clustering algorithm like KMeans. Maybe add in more features like age, duration of employment, ... and play around with the number of clusters $k$ in KMeans and try to interpret the result in a natural language (some early birds, some people check in/out late, ...)

Comment: Yes they check-in and check-out daily except off days/holidays. Should I average the numeric features over a month period, instead of a day.

Comment: You could do that but what would be the point? The 'averaging' is the job of the clustering algorithm... What you could do in order to make life a little easier for the clustering algorithm is to insert features like "'usual' check in/out time / 'usual' duration, ... for this employee" and by usual I mean the avg over the last 3 (or more) days.

Answer (score 0):

**Extract features** that capture what you are interested in.

For example: number if checkins per day, average duration per day, median time of presence (or Q25, Q75) etc.

Features are better than raw data.